# Azure Face Cognitive Service takes to long to return

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Microsoft Azure Face to detect the age and gender from webcam pictures.

The code I'm using is from this Microsoft repository: https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Python/tree/master/cognitive_face

The response time is taking around 2.5 to 3.5 seconds and, in my application case, this is too long.

Since I'm still using azure free account, the server is West Central US (which is not the closest to my server).

Beside changing the server, Is there any other thing I can do to reduce the response time? Or any cloud service will work like this? Then, I'll only be able to reduce the time by changing to a local SDK from other supplier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network latency is probably what you'll have to focus on, the size of the image, also the pricing tier you're using for how many transactions you have per minute, and how many parameters you are requesting.

Answer (score 0):

Face is now in preview for container access - so you could apply(/wait) and host wherever you want:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-how-to-install-containers